# Check all items in a specified checked list box c#

Tags: c#, panel, tablelayoutpanel, checkedlistbox

I have created a small kitchen display program that display food orders. So I created dynamically a panel that contains a table layout panel that contains a checked list box and a check all button . My problem is... I have a check all button in each table layout panel created dynamically and every time I click it, it checks all items in the last created `CheckedListBox` not the clicked one.

This is my code:

```
p = new Panel();
p.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(360, 500);
p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
p.Name = "panel";

tpanel = new TableLayoutPanel();
tpanel.Name = "tablepanel";

clb = new CheckedListBox();

tpanel.Controls.Add(b1 = new Button() { Text = "CheckAll" }, 1, 4);
b1.Name = "b1";
b1.Click += new EventHandler(CheckAll_Click);
b1.AutoSize = true;

private void CheckAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var buttonClicked = (Button)sender;                        
    var c = GetAll(this, typeof(CheckedListBox));

    for (int i = 0; i < c.Count(); i++)
    {
        \\any help
    }
}

public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control, Type type)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl, type)).Concat(controls).Where(c => 
    c.GetType() == type);
}
```

Comment: **it checks all items in the last created checkedlistbox not the clicked one** I don't understand this part. And what is your problem? GetAll() method return empty or what? And this is WinForm, right?

Comment: everytime there is a new order a new panel is created dynamically with the above items(tablelayooutpanel + checkedlistbox and  button) so when i get multiple order i want to check the items in a specific order. for exemple if i have 3 orders then 3 panels will be created. so how i m gonna check all items in the second order. that's my problem

Comment: Ok, I get it. Please wait few minutes for the answer :-)

Comment: and yes this is a windows form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will describe the struct
**Order = TableLayoutPanel**
**TableLayoutPanel** has 1 *CheckAll* **Button** and **CheckListBox**
And you want when you click to *CheckAll* **Button** it will checks exactly all items in current **TableLayoutPanel**.
So try this code

```cs
class XForm : Form {
    // create Dictionary to store Button and CheckListBox
    IDictionary<Button, CheckListBox> map = new Dictionary<Button, CheckListBox> ();

    // when you create new order (new TableLayoutPanel)
    // just add map Button and CheckListBox to map
    private void CreateOrder () {
        var panel = new Panel ();
        panel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size (360, 500);
        panel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        panel.Name = "panel";

        var table = new TableLayoutPanel ();

        var checklistBox = new CheckedListBox ();
        var button = new Button () { Text = "CheckAll" };

        table.Controls.Add (button, 1, 4);
        button.Name = "b1";
        button.Click += new EventHandler (CheckAll_Click);
        button.AutoSize = true;
        map[button] = checklistBox;
    }

    // and on event handle
    private void CheckAll_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var buttonClicked = (Button) sender;
        var c = map[buttonClicked];
        if (c == null) return;
        for (int i = 0; i < c.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            c.SetItemChecked(i, true);
        }
    }
}
```

And dont for get remove it from map when remove the order.
Hope it helps

Comment: on event handle how i m gonna check all items in the checkedlistbox? can you provide me with the rest of the code..thanks in advance